# override the HTML of a single menu block

Tags: routes, theming

Good day all. 
I'm new to drupal, and I could use a little help.
I got the override idea, and I try to stick to this, now, I have a menù, on the upper part of the site, that needs a different HTML from the other ones.
So, first of all, I've overridden the block tpl by adding a file called:

```
block-menu-menu-istitutional.tpl.php
```

but if I take a look at the block.tpl.php all I got are two simple prints:

```
<?php print $block->subject; ?>
<?php print $block->content; ?>
```

What I need is to change what is printed in `$block->content` to add there a markup different from all the other menu blocks.

may someone point me in the right direction? is this the case to override the preprocess function? **but maybe** in this way I'll change *all* the HTML of *all* the menu blocks, isn't it?

Comment: Being new to Drupal I can give you one big piece of advice: use Devel Module and you will be happier! About the preprocess function, you can always filter in an if clause the specific menu... dpm the values and you can sort it out.

Comment: thanks! I'll try the devel module for sure, and now I'm already trying to figure out how to get a specific menu in the way you just proposed...
crossing finger ;)